# Love2D rotating image in a given time until it reaches an angle

Tags: image, lua, rotation, smoothing, love2d

I'm making a little game. It's a 2D game, and the main feature is to change the direction of gravity. I managed to change the direction, so now the player "falls" to the direction fo the gravity. But now i want the player to "stabilize" in eg. 2 seconds. I implemented basic rotation but that instantly changes the angle of the player, and i want it to "slice" the steps to smaller pieces so the rotation will be "smoother". eg. i want to change from 180° to 0° in small steps calculated from the delta time, in relation with a number I input which will be the "duration"

Im not quite familiar with radians and thats why i cant use it.

The gravity direction can be set using world.gravitydir variable, it can be 1,2,3,4. 1 is normal gravity "down" 2,4 is "left" and "right", and 3 is "up"
I also have some "dev commands" to change the gravity direction manually using arrow keys

This is my attempt on rotating the player from upside down to normal smoothly.

```
function rotatePlayer(dt)
deg1 = player.rot -- player's current rotation
step = 0 
        deg2 = math.rad(0) -- desired rotation

        step = (math.deg(deg1) - math.deg(deg2))*dt

            for i = deg1, deg2 do
                player.rot = player.rot - math.rad(step)
                step = step - dt
            end
end
```

playerrotation function is in gravity.lua , and the dev controller, and the player drawing function is in player.lua

Source: http://www.mediafire.com/download/3xto995yz638n0n/notitle.love

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the question is: how? >< because my method is not working

Comment: Just so I'm clear on this, your player is rotating instantly, and you want it to happen over a particular time frame?

Comment: yeah, exactly, to rotate the player smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed a couple issues with your code.

```
deg2 = math.rad(0) -- desired rotation
```

0 radians is equivalent to 0 degrees, so it would seem `deg2` is always zero, thus

```
for i = deg1, deg2 do
```

would only run when `deg1` is equal to or less than zero, which likely means it isn't running as you intended.

Secondly, any variables that don't need to leave their scope should be localized.  This is a Lua best practice.  Your function could be rewritten with locals, for example:

```
function rotatePlayer(dt)
    local deg1 = player.rot -- player's current rotation
    local step = 0 -- ! Any reference to a "step" variable within the scope of this function will always refer to this particular variable.
    local deg2 = 0 -- desired rotation

    step = (math.deg(deg1) - math.deg(deg2))*dt
    for i = deg1, deg2 do
       player.rot = player.rot - math.rad(step)
       step = step - dt
    end
end
```

The following line is equivalent to multiplying the degrees of the player's rotation by the delta `dt`, due to the previously established fact that `deg2` is always zero.

```
    step = (math.deg(deg1) - math.deg(deg2))*dt
```

The following lines are equivalent to taking the player's original rotation in degrees multiplied by the delta (`step`) and subtracting the radians version of that off of the player's current rotation, then subtracting the delta `dt` from the `step` value, inside of a loop which is executed within a single game frame I might add.  I wasn't sure if you were aware that loop is run within one frame.

```
        player.rot = player.rot - math.rad(step)
        step = step - dt
```

I'm not sure what your intention was with those operations, but maybe you can tell me more.

---

As for achieving a smoother animation, you'll need to scale down your rate and adjust how the rotation is carried out.  I've rewritten your function as follows and hope that it, as an example, clarifies how this could be written better:

```
function rotatePlayer(dt) -- dt is seconds since last update
    local current = player.rot -- player's current rotation in radians
    local target = 0 -- desired angle in radians
    local difference = target - current

    if difference == 0 then -- nothing to be done here
        return
    end

    local rate = math.pi / 4 -- radians turned per second (adjust as necessary)
    local change = rate * dt -- r/s * delta(change in time)

    if difference < 0 then
        -- make change negative, since difference is as well
        change = change * -1

        -- If (current + change > target), settle for the lesser difference.
        -- This keeps us from "overshooting" the player's rotation
        -- towards a particular target.
        change = math.max(change, difference)
    else
        change = math.min(change, difference)
    end

    player.rot = current + change
end
```

Please let me know if this resolves your problem and if you have any more questions.

Comment: yeah this gave me the basic idea and its a lot dry-er and cleaner than the method i did (not the one i posted here) BUT, its overshooting, except if i set the gravity to normal, I only changed the "target" variable, its now not local, and it gets it's value like this: 
`if world.gravitydir == 1 then target = 0 end -- down if world.gravitydir == 3 then target = 180 end -- up if world.gravitydir == 2 then target = 90 end -- left if world.gravitydir == 4 then target = 270 end --right`

Comment: Oh actually, i forgot that i should set the values as radians, now its not overshooting :D but now i noticed that from 0° to 270° its going in a positive way instead of substracting it, but I think, i can fix that on my own :D

Answer (score 0):

I've put a change to player.lua on pastebin [Stackoverflow Love2d game](http://pastebin.com/9gNrQCtY) .
It rotates the player at a fixed rate rather than a fixed time. To do the latter just make rottime constant.